# How to Automate Microsoft authenticator using selenium and java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

Step:

Here I will be entering my username

Usernamepage

Next I will enter my password PasswordPage

After the Click on “Sign on” , user will be directed to page which user would have given either two types of Authenication either through OTP (which is send to registered phone) or Authenticator app dynamic number.

Answer (score 3):

I have also solved faced the same problem as you in salesforce, follow below to solve it
As a First step what you need to do is to get the Secret key for the account,In your Account settings in the application there must be a way to reconfigure the 2 factor authentication , open that it will ask you to scan the QR code, instead of that look for a option for secret key and copy that
See below image for reference

[image: example]

Once you have your key ,add below Library in your project to generate the code that is being generated

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>de.taimos</groupId>
        <artifactId>totp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

write a code like this below, this will keep ion printing a new code

```
import de.taimos.totp.TOTP;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class Authenticator {


    public static String getTOTPCode(String secretKey) {
        Base32 base32 = new Base32();
        byte[] bytes = base32.decode(secretKey);
        String hexKey = Hex.encodeHexString(bytes);
        return TOTP.getOTP(hexKey);
    }

    public static void main(String... a) {
    String secretKey = "";
    //add key above

    String code = getTOTPCode(secretKey);

    }
}
```

Once you run the code it will generate a code and enter that to configure your account to use the Verification code which is being generated using the Secret key, this should solved your login issue