# How to automate MFA Microsoft Authentication on Mobile for Selenium Test Cases?

Tags: java, authentication, selenium-webdriver, automation, azure-authentication

I'm using Selenium Java to automate Test cases requiring login into the page to do many steps after that. The problem is if I login into the site, it require to enter the number on Microsoft Authenticator app, which I don't have any idea how to automate this using Selenium (Can not remove the MFA from the test account because privacy policy from the client)

I've researched for this problem and found a solution by:

1. Getting Secret key (following this blog: https://dumbitdude.com/how-to-automate-microsoft-mfa-using-playwright/)
2. Following the post with the same issue: [How to Automate Microsoft authenticator using selenium and java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75834547/how-to-automate-microsoft-authenticator-using-selenium-and-java), with the below answer of @Abhay Chaudhary: I added this dependency add my Secret key to the code below

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>de.taimos</groupId>
        <artifactId>totp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
    public static String getTOTPCode(String secretKey) {
        Base32 base32 = new Base32();
        byte[] bytes = base32.decode(secretKey);
        String hexKey = Hex.encodeHexString(bytes);
        return TOTP.getOTP(hexKey);
    }
```

After excecuting, it generated 6 digit number. But when I choose method "Use a verification code", this 6 digit number was generated in the above code is not valid

Is there any other solutions to automate this Microsoft authentication ? Greatly appreciated with your help !